# Angular wrapper for SignalR event aggregator

Tags: javascript, angular.js, event-handling, wrapper

I created a little wrapper for one of my JavaScript libraries to enable Angular functionality. Are there any pitfalls I should be wary of with my code?

```
angular.module("signalR.eventAggregator", [])
    .run([
        "$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
        function createScope(scope) {
            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                signalR.eventAggregator.unsubscribe(scope);
            });

            return {
                subscribe: function(type, handler, constraint) {
                    signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(type, function(e) {
                        handler(e);
                        if (scope.$$phase == null) {
                            scope.$digest();
                        }
                    }, scope, constraint);
                },
                publish: function(event) {
                    signalR.eventAggregator.publish(event);
                }
            }
        }

        $rootScope.eventAggregator = function() {
            return this.__eventAggregator = this.__eventAggregator || createScope(this);
        };
    }
]);
```

More info on the code itself [here](http://andersmalmgren.com/2015/10/12/client-server-event-aggregation-with-angular/).

It's used like this:

```
$scope.eventAggregator().subscribe(MyApp.MyEvent, onEvent);
```

Other scenarios it supports are

Generic events, (all events are server events proxied to javascript through a dynamic Owin javascript)

```
$scope.eventAggregator().subscribe(MyApp.MyGenericEvent.of("System.String"), onEvent);
```

Constraints, in this case listen to all events with id 5

```
$scope.eventAggregator().subscribe(MyApp.MyEvent, onEvent, { id: 5 });
```

It wraps an event-driven library, and when an event is triggered, I use `digest` to update the view, and it's this part of the code that I wonder about.

`handler(e);` could return a promise that I currently ignore. I tested the `ng-click` directive and it also ignores any promise returned from the click handler. So at least it's consistent with the existing event handlers in Angular.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... interesting use of `run` + `$rootScope`, but I would avoid it primarily because of `$rootScope`. It's essentially the "global space" of an Angular app. The only legit use I see for it is attaching event listeners (`$rootScope.$on`), and for broadcasting events (`$rootScope.$emit`).

As an alternative, you could wrap your event relay in a factory.

- As a factory, the dependency is explicit. The dependent knows it's there and Angular will throw if the dependency is missing on initialization, unlike `$rootScope` where it only throws when you use it.
- Factories are singletons. You don't have to worry about checking and using the existing or create a new one.
- You're not polluting the `$rootScope` nor depending on something that might not be there or have been overridden by something in a lower, enclosing scope. This is a headache to debug, especially without tools like Batarang or ngInspector.

Additionally, you might also want to put your event names in a constant. That way, you have a global lookup of event names, and you won't be hardcoding string literals all over the app.

Here's an example of how it would look like as a factory (using implicit dependency injection syntax for brevity).

```
angular.module('SignalrModule', []);
  .constant('SIGNALR_EVENTS', {
    FOO_EVENT: 'fooevent',
    BAR_EVENT: 'barevent',
  })
  .factory('SignalrFactory', function(){
    return {
      publish: function(){...},
      subscribe: function(){...},
      unsubscribe: function(){...},
    };
  });

angular.module('app', ['SignalrModule'])
  .controller('MyController', function(SignalrFactory, SIGNALR_EVENTS){
    SignalrFactory.subscribe(SIGNALR_EVENTS.FOO_EVENT, function(){
      // on foo event
    });
  });
```

Now I did mention that angular has a built-in pub-sub system. We can just hook on to it so your controllers will simply use regular events over `$rootScope` (we're not adding stuff to `$rootScope`, just making it a relay for events). Not sure of the following works, but the concept is there.

```
angular.module('SignalrModule', []);
  .constant('SIGNALR_EVENTS', {
    FOO_EVENT: 'fooevent',
    BAR_EVENT: 'barevent',
  })
  .run(function($rootScope, SIGNALR_EVENTS){

    // Iterate through our registry of events
    Object.keys(SIGNALR_EVENTS).forEach(function(eventName){

      // Relay angular events to signalr over $rootScope
      $rootScope.$on(SIGNALR_EVENTS[eventName], function(){
        signalR.eventAggregator.publish(SIGNALR_EVENTS[eventName]);
      });

      // Relay signalr events to angular over $rootScope
      signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(SIGNALR_EVENTS[eventName], function(e) {
        $rootScope.$emit(SIGNALR_EVENTS[eventName], e);
      });
    });

  });

angular.module('app', ['SignalrModule'])
  .controller('MyController', function($rootScope, SIGNALR_EVENTS){

    // Using regular angular-ish emit and on

    $rootScope.$emit(SIGNALR_EVENTS.FOO_EVENT, { foo: 'data' });

    $rootScope.$on(SIGNALR_EVENTS.BAR_EVENT, function(){
      // bar event emitted somewhere
    });
  });
```

Comment: This wont work because my event system is much more advanced than angulars, for example you can do $scope.eventAggregator().subscribe(MyApp.MyGenericEvent.of("System.String"), onEvent); etc. But interesting ideas, I will see what I can use. I hav already thought about creating a factory for the signalR.eventAggregator global. That way I can use it for stuff that does not have a scope. Good points, thanks

Comment: Updated question with all valid scenarios

Comment: hmm, also with your version there is not natural place to call unsubscribe. Without unsubscribe the server will keep sending events even if no one is listening client side which is a waste of resources

Comment: @Anders Ahh yeah, wasn't really acquainted with SignalR really, other than that it was some for of event system. Also, usually one doesn't update a question when it has answers, otherwise the answers may become irrelevant. Usually you post a separate question as followup.

Comment: The question remains the same?

Comment: @Anders But the additional points might leave gaps that the original answer didn't cover. But meh, doesn't change my answer anyways. :)

Comment: I think its good to keep it as is, it can help others even if it does not help me 100%. Btw, this is not actually SignalR related. My library is an abstraction ontop of SignalR